# Boto 2.49.0, support for TLS 1.2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tls1.2, boto

I have an old application that has a very old version of boto2 (2.6.0) that doesn't have the support for TLS 1.2
So instead of the costy re-writing of all the application in python3, using boto3, I would like to know if Boto 2.49.0, that was released in ~2017, supports TLS v1.2.

Anyone knows?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd suggest that this is a good opportunity to update your app. Going from Python v2 to v3 and updating boto3 to the latest might not be as bad as you think and should bring numerous security improvements.